# Is there any way of discovering which DirectShow filter in a graph sent a DirectShow event?

Tags: directshow

The IMediaEvent and IMediaEventEx do not say which filter in a graph sent the retrieved DirectShow event. Is there any way of finding this information. In particular for graphs where one of the filters in the graph sends an EC_ERRORABORT event?

Ideally would be nice to have something suitable for production systems but hacky solutions that will work just for in house debugging would also be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, with `EC_ERRORABORT` event code you just have `HRESULT` value to possibly help you.

UPD. With certain luck [DirectShow Spy](http://alax.info/blog/1385) can shed some more light.

Comment: Is there any way this information could be derived from your Direct Show Spy tool? I can see QueryInterfaces for IMediaEvent in the logs. Do columns 2 and 3 indicate anything about the caller?

Comment: Not really. There is no such information in first place "who sent the event code". On the spy tool I could possibly trace stack at the time of the event, to at least know the DLL which was the source. This is good idea, but I will yet have to add this.

Comment: I added call stack logging for `EC_ERRORABORT`, see [DirectShow Spy: Who Sent EC_ERRORABORT?](http://alax.info/blog/1385).